# Adding Pagination to a wordpress post list

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to add pagination to this post list https://cutt.ly/tjuH6lJ , the code i used was

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
<!-- the shortcode to the list -->
...............................
<script> 
var myList = new List('main_blog', {
valueNames: ['pis-li'],
page: 3,
pagination: true
});
</script>
```

I also tried the PHP pagination code and added it to my functions.php

```
function pagination_nav() {
global $wp_query;

if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) { ?>
    <nav class="pagination" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts' ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?></div>
    </nav>
<?php }}
```

and invoke it with `<?php pagination_nav(); ?>`

i am using the "Extra" theme from "DIVI" and the post list was made with a plugin called "Posts in Sidebar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `the_posts_pagination()` function.

> Displays a paginated navigation to next/previous set of posts, when applicable.

- *Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_posts_pagination/*

It uses the arguments of the `get_the_posts_pagination` and `paginate_links()` functions.

> See `get_the_posts_pagination()` for available arguments.

- *Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_posts_pagination/*
- *Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/*

---

### Pagination & loop

```
<?php
if( have_posts() ):
  while( have_posts() ): the_post();

    echo '<article>';
    if( get_the_title() !== '' ):
      esc_attr( the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' ) );
    endif;
    if( get_the_content() !== '' ):
      esc_attr( the_content() );
    endif;
    echo '<article>';

  endwhile;

  /**
  * the_posts_pagination
  * Displays a paginated navigation to next/previous set of posts, when applicable.
  * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_posts_pagination/
  * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_posts_pagination/
  * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/
  */
  the_posts_pagination( array(
    'screen_reader_text'  => ' ',
    'prev_text'           => '&#x2190;',
    'next_text'           => '&#x2192;',
    'show_all'            => true,
  ) );

  else:

    echo 'No posts yet!';

endif; ?>
```

If I remember correctly by default, Wordpress will show 12 posts, before showing the pagination.